# Repeating animation in Android

Tags: android

I have defined six animations like `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `a4`, `a5` and `a6` for six image views. These animations are performed in a sequence. For instance, `a2` will start when `a1` ends, `a3` will start when `a2` ends and so on. Starting from `a1`, the animation ends with `a6`. Now I want to repeat again from `a1` to `a6`. Where should I write this `setRepeatMode`? How to achieve this in some other way? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) on your `a6` animation and have it restart everything?

In fact for your chain of animations, the usage of `AnimationListener` might be helpful.

Comment: i ve used animation listener only to achieve that chaining.

Comment: could u pls tell which animation i should restart to repeat the chain.That is my doubt

Comment: The first one .. based on your explanation. Maybe post some code.